# Google leaderBoard implementation in cocs2d-x for android game?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, google-api, cocos2d-x, leaderboard

Has anyone implemented google leaderboard on cocos2d-x for android project? 
I couldn't find an  efficient solution to integrate java API in cocos2d-x game it.
What I guess - we can configure cocos2d-x game for google play services and use JNI calls from our game scene. I am newbie working on first app, couldn't figure out how to do this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very detailed
this is your need: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/28296